# How to drag the p:dialog without use showHeader="true" in primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am developing a project using primefaces.

In that, I used one `p:panel`(in user.xhtml page) inside the `p:dialog` and I set `showHeader="false"` to the `p:dialog`.

For that, I need to drag the `p:dialog` when I click and drag on the `p:panel`, which is included inside the `p:dialog`.

**Sample Code:**

```
<p:dialog showHeader="false">      

     <ui:include src="${model.dynamicPage}"/>     

</p:dialog>
```

**user.xhtml**

```
<h:form id="userForm">
   <p:panel header="UserPanel">
     .......
   </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `draggable` component on a panel instead of a dialog

```
<p:panel id="pnl" header="UserPanel">      
     <ui:include src="${model.dynamicPage}"/>     
</p:panel>
<p:draggable for="pnl" />
```

and define the panel dimensions with some css:

```
.ui-panel {
    margin: 15px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

**Edit**: if there are several components in your `model.dynamicPage` facelet but you want the panel to be the only allowed to handle the dragging of the whole container, add a css class to it and restrict the draggable component handling with this class:

eg.

```
<p:panel id="pnl" showHeader="false">      
     <ui:include src="${model.dynamicPage}"/>     
</p:panel>
<p:draggable for="pnl" handle=".my-handle-classname" />
```

and

```
<h:form id="userForm">
   <p:panel header="UserPanel" styleClass="my-handle-classname">
     .......
   </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. i hope it ll help to mine project.

Comment: @Zim....Your code was working fine, but it does not suit for my expectations. I need to drag the p:panel which is included inside of the p:dialog. When the p:panel draggable then that p:dialog also draggable based on the p:panel(position).

Comment: I need to include 3 pages inside of the p:dialog using ui:include. So I get two heads, one from p: dialog and 2nd from p:panel so there view is not good so I removed one head of p:dialog. By that without p:dialog head can't drag the p:dialog so I had an idea to drag the p: panel.

Comment: ya i tried.....its working fine for drag the panel....not inside p:panel of p:dialog.....If i drag the panel which is inside of the p:dialog that p:panel only drag not p:dialog.

Comment: I think you'll have to use only `p:panel` components, no `p:dialog`. Thus, this works fine:
`<p:panel id="pnl" showHeader="false"
    style="width:300px; height: 200px">
    <p:panel header="Greet" style="width: 100%; height: 100px;"
     styleClass="foo">
     Hello world!
    </p:panel>
   </p:panel>
   <p:draggable for="pnl" handle=".foo" />`

Comment: hmm k....but I need p:dialog bcoz its only ll appear on page but p:panel does not show as p:dialog so only...

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean... The `p:panel` doesn't fit because you want the dialog to be initially hidden?